# Populating a NSImageView inside NSTouchBar

Tags: swift, macos, macos-sierra, nstouchbar

I'm currently creating a tiny [open source app](https://github.com/touchbar/Touch-Bar-Preview) to preview an inside the new Touch Bar.
I have a window with a drag n drop view to receive images via it's URL. And a IB Touch Bar with a NSImageView inside a TouchBarView.
[interface builder structure (screenshot)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PvSpJ.png)

This is working in my `MainViewController` to show the image in the window:

```
extension ViewController: DropDestinationViewDelegate {

    func processImageURLs(_ urls: [URL]) {
        for (_,url) in urls.enumerated() {

            // pass URL to Window Controller
            let windowController = WindowController()
            windowController.showImageInTouchBar(url)

            // create the image from the content URL
            if let image = NSImage(contentsOf:url) {

                imagePreviewView.image = image
            }
        }
    }

}
```

As you can see I use a delegate to listen to the drag n drop events to get the image URL. Now I want to use the image/URL to show the same image inside the Touch Bar. I've created the Touch Bar with Interface Builder and I'm passing the image-url to the `WindowController`.

In my `WindowController` I try to handle the image like this:

```
class WindowController: NSWindowController {

    @IBOutlet var touchBarImageView: NSImageView!

    override func windowDidLoad() {
        super.windowDidLoad()
    }

    func showImageInTouchBar(_ url: URL) {
        print(url)

        if let touchbarImage = NSImage(contentsOf:url) {
            touchBarImageView.image = touchbarImage
        }
    }
}
```

I'm receiving the correct URL with `print(url)`, but when I try to create the image again, the app is crashing with the following message:

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

Comment: Check if _touchBarImageView_ is not a nil. Aren't you calling _showImageInTouchBar_ before the controller is loaded?

Comment: Ahh good hint! Thanks! The `touchBarImageView` is indeed nil. **But why?** If I populate the ImageView in my `MainViewController` I don't have to do anything. And no sorry, I'm calling the `showImageInTouchBar()`after the `windowDidLoad()`.

Comment: Can you make a commit with your current code to separate branch?

Comment: Sure, I've created a new branch with the latest approach [here](https://github.com/touchbar/Touch-Bar-Preview/commits/develop) (with commit [492f6ab](https://github.com/touchbar/Touch-Bar-Preview/commit/492f6ab6672044cf2379a6b267783c9f595512d9)). Feel free to create a pull request if you want the contribution. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a pull request with a fix.

Your problem was that you was creating a new *WindowController* and using this as reference instead using the controller created and used  by *NSWindow*.

Result:

[image]